# Django multiple database routing. Missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I am trying to link an external database to my Django project in order to perform validation.

I have tried my best to follow the official django tutorials on routing and other sources and have managed to get to the point where my database is recognised and the model is read.

However, when I enter the shell and try to access one of the models associated with this db, like so:

```py
from get_ext.models import ExternalTable

ExternalTable.objects.all()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ADAMGH~1\DOCUME~1\Project\COLLEC~1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\ADAMGH~1\DOCUME~1\Project\COLLEC~1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\ADAMGH~1\DOCUME~1\Project\COLLEC~1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\ADAMGH~1\DOCUME~1\Project\COLLEC~1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    db = queryset.db
  File "C:\Users\ADAMGH~1\DOCUME~1\Project\COLLEC~1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1170, in db
    return self._db or router.db_for_read(self.model, **self._hints)
  File "C:\Users\ADAMGH~1\DOCUME~1\Project\COLLEC~1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 257, in _route_db
    chosen_db = method(model, **hints)
TypeError: db_for_read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
```

Here is the current setup of my dbs, router and model:

settings.py

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'colltooldb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432' 
    },
    'external': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'externaldb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432' 
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [get_ext.routers.ExtRouter]
```

get_ext/models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class ExternalTable(models.Model):
    '''
    FIELDS
    '''

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'external_table'
```

get_ext/routers.py

```py
class ExtRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'get_ext':
            return 'external'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'get_ext':
            return 'external'
        return None
```

What is causing this error?

I recognise, that I don't really have a lot of knowledge in this particular domain, so let me know if I'm missing any crucial information that you would need to answer my question and I should be able to update it fairly rapidly.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Sure, it's added now

Comment: @arassi you need quotes around `get_ext.routers.ExtRouter`.

Comment: `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["get_ext.routers.ExtRouter"]`

Comment: The quotes did it. Thanks Nalin!